# Glossaries list doesn't display

Tags: color, glossaries, article, glossaries-extra

I have a list of glossaries as shown below included in my code but the list of glossaries isn't displayed. Please help. Here is my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\makeglossary
% abbreviations:
\newglossaryentry{nmhs}{name={NMHSs},description={National Meteorological and Hydrological Services}}
\newglossaryentry{wmo}{name={WMO},description={World Meteorological Organization}}
\newglossaryentry{imo}{name={IMO},description={International Meteorological Organization}}
\newglossaryentry{hdd}{name={HDD},description={Heating Degree Day}}
\newglossaryentry{cdd}{name={CDD},description={Cooling Degree Day}}
\newglossaryentry{gts}{name={GTS},description={Global Telecommunication System}}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\printglossary

According to \gls{wmo} and its predecessor \gls{imo} all \gls{nmhs} should produce lists of \gls{hdd} and \gls{cdd} all transmitted to \gls{gts}            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex myfile`, `makeglossaries myfile`, `pdflatex myfile`? When I do this with your example, the document contains the glossary.

Comment: What do you mean by running `pdflatex myfile, makeglossaries myfile, pdflatex myfile`? Perhaps this is what I am missing out.

Comment: I am using TexStudio on Windows 10 OS

Comment: I have just install TeXstudio under Linux, and here you have to say `Tools | Compile`, then `Tools | Glossary`, and again `Tools | Compile`.

Comment: I get this error when I try above `makeglossaries.exe: The script engine could not be found. makeglossaries.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"`

Comment: I found the solution to the above error by installing Perl [here](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/downloads/). Now everything works fine